# Incorrect Integer Value: How do i convert my Data from String to Int to avoid Auto_Increment?

Tags: java, string, netbeans, int, auto-increment

Im having troubles converting my String to integer. My Data Table consist of 3 columns, two of which are INT type. But when i started inserting my String to my Database it gives an Auto_Increment error:

Class:

```
public class Strong extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  String a;

    public Apply() {
        initComponents();
         jTable1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
            {
                int selectedRow = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
                a = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);


            }
        }
        );

    }
```

My executeUpdate:

```
try{

           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/application","root","");
            String sql= "insert into Mycart values(?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);            
            pst.setString(1, (String)a);
            pst.setString(2, (String)a);
            pst.setString(3, (String)a);

            pst.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added to Cart");

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

This is actually a follow up regarding my previous question. My Question is that how can i convert my String to Integer and then insert it on my Database? If you might ask i got my String from my jTable which then got it from my database. What i want to do now is that get the values inside that jTable and insert it to a new Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cast object to string as below

```
 String a = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0)); 

 pst.setString(1, a);
```

In case Your target field type is integer do this.

```
 pst.setInt(1,Integer.ParseInt(a));
```

Comment: Show your table structure (Auto_increment) field for better consideration.

Comment: I still received the error. In your own method how would you insert a String value to an Int type data table? I really need an example.

Comment: Im looking for a way to insert my String to my Database but everytime i run it this error appear: Incorrect Integer value: "SGS2" for column "Price" at row 1.

Comment: I've look at the codes repeatedly and i've realized that this code is partly to blame: int selectedRow = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
                a = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);

I think this code only take the values of my "Model" Row. It does not take the rest of the rows(Price, Stock). Any way to edit this?

Comment: Is it possible for us to have Teamviewer? So that you can explore my codes? Just a suggestion, but if not then its ok.

Comment: yes of cource@ChesterVacalares .share your details.

Comment: id: 497 747 015  pass: 5678

Comment: Thank you so much. The code is working now. All i did was changed the .SelectedRowCount(); to .getSelected(); and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a String to an Integer by using the `Integer.toString()` method. Just pass the string in as the parameter.

Comment: After i've converted the String how do i then insert it to my database? What method should i use?

Comment: Is this method? Or should i convert the String first before i insert it:

pst.setString(2, Integer.toString(a));

Comment: Id: 497 747 015 Pass: 5678

Comment: Use the method that takes an integer as an input. Your IDE should tell you this.

Answer (score 0):

By assuming that your auto_increment field is you primary key and you're trying to put the first value there, it is better try this.

```
        String sql= "insert into Mycart (your_string_field, your_int_field) values(?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, "your_data_goes_here"); // for string
        pst.p.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt("your_data_goes here")); // for integer

        pst.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added to Cart");
```

**Note :-**
For auto increment fields in databases, you don't need to add a value in inserting. That is why it is called auto_increment. So I removed first field so the second field became your first prepared statement parameter.

Hope it helps.